# PHP regex examples

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, capture-group

I am a beginner learning PHP. I am trying out various combinations with regex. I am referring to [this](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) and trying out examples on [this](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php).

My doubts:

1. Why does `preg_match_all('((a|b)*c)', 'ababc', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);` give both `ababac` and `a` as output. Shouldn't it be just `ababac`?
2. Assuming that I'm trying to read all possible outputs in `$arr`, how do I do that without having to echo each element of the array? Currently, I'm using `foreach` to iterate the elements in `$arr`. Is this right / is there a better way to do it?
3. Why does the `preg_match_all()` give a 2D array with elements `$arr[$i][0]` and in some cases `$arr[0][$i]`  where `$i` is no of of possible matches. Is there a way to know how the output will be stored?

Sorry for posting too many questions in one post. Please tell me if I need to change it.

Comment: Lets start by the first one: can you put the `var_dump($arr)` that we see what it gives ?

Comment: echo var_dump($arr); gives me  array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "ababac" [1]=> string(1) "a" } }

Answer (score 3):

1. The `(a|b)` is a captured subpattern, therefore it is returned as part of the result array. You can make it non-capturing by using `(?:a|b)`, but it would be far better as a character class, `[ab]`.
2. `foreach` is probably the best way to go about it.
3. As mentioned in 1, you will get your subpatterns captured and returned in the array.

You may want to look into [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback), as this will apply a given callback (usually an anonymous function) to each match.

Comment: Sorry I dont get the ?: part. What does : mean? I know ? means 0 or one character.

Comment: @PRamesh: Non-capturing group. You don't need to get the text matched by the pattern inside `()`, you only need the grouping property, so non-capturing group `(?:pattern)` is what you want.

Comment: *"I know ? means 0 or one character"* That's like saying "I know `I` means "me", so what does "in" mean?"

Comment: @nhahtdh- Ok. but why not it return b too if (a|b) is evaluated as a subpattern?

Comment: Because a repeated subpattern only returns the last one.